# Audio not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to get audio to play in general, but it does not seem to be working. I thought perhaps the interval or if statements were stopping it from playing, but as you can see even a call before all that does not make any sound. The directory is in the right place and the files are for sure there. There is also a little "<>" symbol on the page, I have no idea why. Here is the HTML that runs the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flash/Beepo</title>
  Flash/Beep Test
</head>
<button id="b2" onclick=startFlash()>Start</button>
<script src="scripts/Flashbeep.js"></script>
<img src='images/unnamed.jpg' alt='blinking!' id='blink' />
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="beep" src="sounds/beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="2beep" src="sounds/2beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="3beep" src="sounds/3beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="4beep" src="sounds/4beep.wav"></audio>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the script:

```
function startFlash(){
  var img = document.getElementById('blink');
  var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*(3))+1
  var count=0
  var q= Math.floor(Math.random() +.5)
  document.getElementById('beep').play();//no sound
  if(q==0) {


    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (count == i) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
      if (img.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        count = count + 1
      } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }, 17);
  }else{


    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (count == 1) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
      if (img.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('beep').play();//no sound
        count = count + 1
      } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }, 17);


  }
}
```

Comment: The audio is working here... see this fiddle, I just put the script declaration just before the Start button... http://jsfiddle.net/jmxq51qx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working audio code... I just moved the function declaration on top of the Start button. Please try it in your end if it works.

```
<script>
    function startFlash(){
  var img = document.getElementById('blink');
  var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*(3))+1
  var count=0
  var q= Math.floor(Math.random() +.5)
  document.getElementById('beep').play();//no sound
  if(q==0) {


    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (count == i) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
      if (img.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        count = count + 1
      } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }, 17);
  }else{


    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
      if (count == 1) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
      if (img.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('beep').play();//no sound
        count = count + 1
      } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }, 17);


  }
}
</script>

<button id="b2" onclick=startFlash()>Start</button>
<!--<script src="scripts/Flashbeep.js"></script>-->
<img src='http://www.colgate.fi/ColgateOralCare/ElectricToothbrush/ProClinical/common/images/icons/red-dot.png' alt='blinking!' id='blink' />
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="beep" src="http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/70/70106_1022651-lq.mp3"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="2beep" src="sounds/2beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="3beep" src="sounds/3beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="4beep" src="sounds/4beep.wav"></audio>
<body>

</body>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jmxq51qx/)

Comment: As I have the function in a separate .js file, I assume you mean arrange it like :  <script src="scripts/Flashbeep.js"></script>
<button id="b2" onclick=startFlash()>Start</button>
<img src='images/unnamed.jpg' alt='blinking!' id='blink' />
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="beep" src="sounds/beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="2beep" src="sounds/2beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="3beep" src="sounds/3beep.wav"></audio>
<audio style="visibility:hidden" id="4beep" src="sounds/4beep.wav"></audio>

Comment: yes, declare the script on top of the button that calls it, probably inside the `<head>`